# Use RealmObject with Recyclerview ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

Since RealmObject can only be accessed within the thread they were created it is not possible to use it with **ListAdapter** because of the use of **AsyncListDiffer**
In this case you will get this exception

> Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

Is there an alternative ? My first suggestion would be map RealmObject into Pojo that represent the view data but as there is a lot of change on the list, it will slow down the UI Thread.

Comment: why do you need to use AsyncListDiffer ?

Comment: It improves performance, for example when an item is updated, only the corresponding view will be updated instead of all views displayed in the recyclerview. At the same time it allows you to catch the element that has changed

Comment: The point to use Realm is to use it's reactivity, so you can use something like this : https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters It'll warn the adapter that objects has been inserted, deleted or updated, and it'll update only modified views ;)

Comment: Correct, use the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: Did you find the way? The only way that I found is set the main thread to the AsyncDiffConfig. `AsyncDifferConfig.Builder<Audio>(ITEM_CALLBACK)
            .setBackgroundThreadExecutor(Dispatchers.Main.asExecutor())
            .build()`. I wonder if there is better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Realm.copyFromRealm()` available since `0.87.0` to make copy of an already persisted RealmObject.

Answer (score -1):

If in your DiffUtil.ItemCallback you just do simple comparison then you could wrap your Realm data with a class.

```
class User: RealmObject {
   @PrimaryKey
   var uuid: String? = null
}
data class WrappedUserData(val uuid: Long, val user: User)
```

Then use that class to be the adapter's item type

```
class MyAdapter: ListAdapter<WrappedUserData, ItemViewHolder>
```

And use the wrapped class to compare.

```
private val ITEM_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<WrappedUserData>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: WrappedUserData, newItem: WrappedUserData): Boolean {
        return oldItem.uuid == newItem.uuid
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: WrappedUserData, newItem: WrappedUserData): Boolean {
        return oldItem.uuid == newItem.uuid
    }
}
```

When when you call `myAdapter.submitList` you just need to map your original data to WrappedUser list.

Comment: The method `areContentsTheSame` must compare the content of the two items. In your example, if a user property changes (e.g username), you will not see it because you only compare the uuid.